# knockout-validation custom error message for pattern validator using html5 syntax

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the HTML5 syntax of knockout-validation to validate that the user has entered a valid number like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Lots" pattern="^\d*\.?\d*$" />
```

It works great, but the error message just says `'Invalid!'.`
Is there a way to customize the validation message that appears when using the HTML% syntax?

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10554179

Answer (score 0):

the following seems to set the validation message:

```
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'customized validation message!';
```