# Custom Error message for minLength Knockout Validations

Tags: knockout.js, range, knockout-validation

I am working with knockout validations . I want to display custom message for min and max length .I have tried with some options and I cant able to achieve it.if anyone achieved it already, please share me how I can do that.

here is what I am trying right now.

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({
        minLength: [
            3,
             'Please enter Valid number']

        , maxLength: 10
    }),
}
```

Do I have to really go for the RegEx for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In you want to provide a custom message you need pass in an object to the validation rule (`minLength`) with a `params` property holding the parameter and a `message` property with the new message:

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({
        minLength: { params: 3, message: "Please enter Valid number" }
        , maxLength: 10
    }),
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezfr8/).

Comment: yeah.. I have passed the parameter as param missed (s).Thanks for making it up.

Answer (score 1):

To customize [Native-Rules](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules) you need to pass literal object with properties that you want to customize:

For Example:

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({
        minLength: {
            params:3,
            message:'Please enter Valid number'
         }
        , maxLength: 10
    }),
}
```

To get more understanding kindly check this [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552625/set-a-custom-error-message-using-the-native-rules-of-the-knockout-validation-plu#10554179)